# wysiwyg + html5 images copy paste?

Tags: jquery, html, wysiwyg

Which open source wysiwyg editor allows the functionality of uploading images to the server by copy pasting the images into the text-area from the clipboard (like gmail)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this plugin](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=23646) with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com).